# Level shifting of a 3 state pin

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, resistors, analog, battery-charging

I want to design a simple battery charger using [MCP73831/2](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001984g.pdf). This chip has a 3-State state pin according to the table below:

[image]

I have a 3.3V MCU and I want to connect this pin to a GPIO. The MCU is not 5V tolerant and maximum votlage on any pin is given 3.6V per datasheet (esp32).

My question is, how can I safely connect this STAT pin to my MCU? How can I translate its HIGH state (which is I guess 5V) to 3.3 and its LOW state to 0V (logic low). Is a resistor divider enough for this? or will I need to use mosfet or transistors? Here is my circuit:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a potential divider is fine.

Use a 10K upper resistor and 20K lower resistor, or higher values, rather than 1K and 2K. That avoids drawing current needlessly.

You can't detect the high-Z output this way, though, but your question implies that you don't want to.

Comment: Thanks a lot. while you are at it , can you also mention what about HIGH-Z?

Comment: @DEKKER, what exactly are you asking? I have mentioned high-Z.

Comment: High-Z will appear as a low to the MCU. R3 will pull it down and the other end of R2 will effectively be disconnected.

Comment: If you had to detect the in-coming high-Z state it could be done, but it would required using an additional I/O line, (or an adc input).  Inquire if that is even needed.